# Problem up loading to board

Tags: servo

I'm a newbee to Arduino programming and hoping someone can help me with this. These are the errors when uploading the proceeding sketch. Thanks in advance!

avrdude: stk500_rcv() : programmer is not 
responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10:not in sync:

Problem uploading to board.

```c
//www.RobotLinking.com
//2015.5.7
/************************************************/
#include <Servo.h>
/************************************************/
Servo myservo;//create servo object to control a servo
/************************************************/
void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(9);//attachs the servo on pin 9 to servo object
  myservo.write(0);//back to 0 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second
}
/*************************************************/
void loop()
{  
  myservo.write(15);//goes to 15 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second
  myservo.write(30);//goes to 30 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second.33
  myservo.write(45);//goes to 45 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second.33
  myservo.write(60);//goes to 60 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second.33
  myservo.write(75);//goes to 75 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second.33
  myservo.write(90);//goes to 90 degrees
  delay(1000);//wait for a second
  myservo.write(75);//back to 75 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second.33
  myservo.write(60);//back to 60 degrees
  delay(1000);//wait for a second.33
  myservo.write(45);//back to 45 degrees
  delay(1000);//wait for a second.33
  myservo.write(30);//back to 30 degrees
  delay(1000);//wait for a second.33
  myservo.write(15);//back to 15 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second
  myservo.write(0);//back to 0 degrees 
  delay(1000);//wait for a second
}
/**************************************************/
```

Comment: if you google for `avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10:not in sync:` there is a lot of topics and possible answers that could suit your needs.

Comment: Which board? Which OS? What is wired to the board? Is it a genuine one or a clone?

Comment: Oh, the formatting -.- anyway... Can you upload another sketch on the board? Usually people use the blink example...

Comment: Code formatting is fubared. You need to put four spaces in front of each line...

Answer (score 1):

One of the first things to know about Arduinos is that that there are a lot of them – and a lot of tools for programming them. For your problem this means that the most likely reason for the problem you are having is a mismatch between the board your are using and the board your tools are set to upload to. Since you've said you're new to the Arduino I'm assuming that you're using the "official" IDE.

So, here are some things to try:

1. From the IDE main menu, choose **Tools > Board** and select your board, then
2. Choose **Tools > Programmer** and select an appropriate programmer for your board. Without knowing what board you're using and how you're connecting to it I can't offer more specific advice. However, if you Google for something like "beginner tutorial " you're likely to find an answer. Or more likely three answers. You'll need to look at the one that matches the OS you're using on your development machine.
3. You may also need to select the port that the Arduino is connected to.

If you've gotten this far and haven't solved the problem, here's what I'd do next:

1. Do a search on the exact error message you're getting – copy it out of the IDE and the paste it into your favorite search engine. Put quotes around the message so that you don't get a bunch of unrelated hits for your search.
2. Search for tutorials on the board and/or IDE vendor site.
3. Work through a tutorial from a good beginner's site. I like the [materials the Adafruit folks have developed](https://learn.adafruit.com/lesson-0-getting-started/overview), but there are lots of good resources out there.
4. Post a question. When you do be sure to:

   - Describe your environment: the board you're using, the IDE you're using, the OS you're working on, how the board is connected to the development machine, and the basic settings of the IDE.
   - Explain what you've tried.
   - Describe, or better, include a screen shot or the actual text of the problem that you're seeing (like you did here).
   - For some problems it will also be useful to include the code. If you include the complete code then it is possible that somebody could try to actually reproduce your problem.

Comment: I think I may have found the answer to my problem. Like I mentioned I am new to the Arduino world. I did not burn the 432 on the UNO. How come the 432 isn't burned at the factory. I'm I proceeding in the right direction to burn the 432? Excuse my ignorance!